# Problems with Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

I'm having some troubles when it comes to multiplying two matrices. An *AttributeError* appears when I'm trying to perform the addition part

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MatrixClass.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
  File "MatrixClass.py", line 184, in main
    mat.multiplyMatrixes(mat1,mat2)
  File "MatrixClass.py", line 176, in multiplyMatrixes
    self[i][j] += (m1[i][k])*(m2[k][j]) 
AttributeError: matrix instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I tried saving the new matrix in another instance called for example m3 but the I thought it would be better to use *self* instead.

Here's my code:

```
def multiplyMatrices(self,m1,m2):
    if m1.getRows() == m2.getColumns() and m1.getColumns() == m2.getRows():
        self.setRows()
        self.setColumns()
        for i in range(m1.getRows()):
            for j in range(m2.getColumns()):
                for k in range(m1.getColumns()):
                    self[i][j] += (m1[i][k])*(m2[k][j])
```

I created the instance of self in *main()*, before calling *multiplyMatrices()*

Comment: Does your matrix class actually have a `__getitem__` method?

Comment: How can I know that? I implemented getValue(file,column), getRows() & getColumns()

Comment: Well, you wrote it, didn't you? Did you write a `__getitem__` method? (If you did, is it still there when you look for it? And is the name right?)

Comment: This is confusing. If you get this to work, the call `m0.multiplyMatrices(m1, m2)` is going to end up replacing the contents of `m0` with `m1 * m2` Why would you want that? Can you show us (a stripped-down version of) your class definition, and describe what the API is supposed to be?

Comment: Note that getter and setter functions (especially this usage) are unpythonic - prefer raw attributes or `@property`s

Comment: Also, the requirement for valid multiplication is only that `m1.getColumns() == m2.getRows()`. The other condition you use is not a requirement

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using numpy?

Comment: A triple nested loop just looks nasty, especially in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `AttributeError`, you never defined the `__getitem__` method in your class. [This](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) is how you can control object[key] access. I would suggest reading up on the python [data model](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) in general if you are deciding to make a more advanced class (like this one) in python. Although it is a bit strange to have the multiplication of two *other* matrices being stored in self. I'd probably just create a new matrix in the method and return that.